# Struct com ponteiro e alocação

Tags: c, struct, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Não consigo usar o `fscanf` numa estrutura, eu já aloquei  as estruturas.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Cliente
{
    int numero;
    char *nome;
};
struct Filme
{
    int numero;
    char * nome;
};
struct Data
{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
};
struct Emprestimo
{
    int numero;
    int ativo;
    Cliente *cliente;
    Filme *filme;
    Data *emprestimo;
    Data *devolucao;
};

void verifica_erro(FILE *arquivo)  //verifica se deu erro ao abrir o arquivo
{
    if(arquivo==NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo!");
        exit(0);
    }
}
void carrega_empre(Emprestimo *video) //carrega na memoria os dados do cliente
{
    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo=fopen("emprestimos.txt","rt");
    verifica_erro(arquivo);
    int cont=0;
    while(!feof(arquivo))
    {
        fscanf(arquivo,"%d %d %d" ,&video[cont].numero,&video[cont].cliente->numero,&video[cont].filme->numero);
        fscanf(arquivo,"%d %d %d %d " ,&video[cont].emprestimo->dia,&video[cont].emprestimo->mes,&video[cont].emprestimo->ano,&video[cont].ativo);
        fscanf(arquivo,"%d %d %d",&video[cont].devolucao->dia,&video[cont].devolucao->mes,&video[cont].devolucao->ano);
        cont++;
        cont++;
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
}
int conta_registros(char *caminho) //conta quatos registros tem no txt para alocar na         strutura
{
    FILE *arquivo;
    char caracter;
    int linhas=0;
    arquivo=fopen(caminho,"rt");
    while((caracter = fgetc(arquivo)) != EOF)
    {
        if(caracter == '\n')  //cada linha eh um registro
        {
            linhas++;
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
   return linhas;
}
int main()
{
    int regE;
    Emprestimo *video;
    regE=conta_registros("emprestimos.txt");
    video=(Emprestimo*)malloc(regE+20*sizeof(Emprestimo)); 

    carrega_empre(video);
    printf("acabo\n");
    scanf("%*c");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Poste um modelo/exemplo do arquivo que você está tentando ler.

Answer (score 2):

Depois de alocar memoria para `video`, tens que alocar para `video->cliente`, para `video->filme`, `video->emprestimo`, e `video->devolucao`.

```
int main()
{
    Emprestimo *video;
    video = malloc(regE * sizeof *video); /* falta validacao de erro */
    for (int k = 0; k < regE; k++) {
        video->cliente = malloc(sizeof *video->cliente); /* falta validacao de erro */
        video->filme = malloc(sizeof *video->filme); /* falta validacao de erro */
        // etc ...
    }
```

Comment: entao mesmoa assim nao vai cara! pode tentar com o codigo ai

Answer (score 0):

Existe um erro na linha:

> video=(Emprestimo*)malloc(regE+20*sizeof(Emprestimo));

Se `regE` contém a quantidade de registros, então falta um par de `()` para fazer com que a multiplicação dê o resultado esperado, alocando a quantidade de memória necessária:

```
video=(Emprestimo*)malloc((regE+20)*sizeof(Emprestimo));
```